# Why does the inverse Alexander polynomial appear in the MMR conjecture?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, qa.quantum-algebra, topological-quantum-field-theory, alexander-polynomial

In an attempt to better understand why the *inverse* Alexander polynomial appears in the MMR conjecture, I was reading the paper [1] of Bar-Natan and Garoufalidis giving their proof of the conjecture using weight systems. In particular, they discuss Rozansky's path-integral "proof" of the conjecture in section 1.4. I mostly follow this argument, except for the following claim:

> Cheeger and Mueller proved that the Ray-Singer torsion is equal to the Reidemeister torsion, which by Milnor and Turaev was shown to be proportional to the inverse of the Alexander polynomial $A(K)$ of $K$.

My understanding was that Milnor and Turaev show that the torsion is proportional to the Alexander polynomial, not its inverse.
Am I wrong? Is it a different torsion than the one I'm thinking of?

The torsion involves an alternating product, so it could just be different conventions.
In that case understanding why this convention is right probably means digging deeper into the proof.

[1] [On the Melvin–Morton–Rozansky conjecture](https://doi.org/10.1007/s002220050070)

Comment: I think that Turaev and Milnor have different conventions for Reidemeister torsion. One relates Reidemeister torsion to the Alexander polynomial, the other to its inverse.

Comment: You're right: usually in the topology literature the torsion is normalized so it agrees with the Alexander polynomial, and in the analysis literature the inverse is used instead.

Comment: However, that brings up the question of why the asymptotics of the colored Jones polynomial (a.k.a. the semiclassical behavior of quantum Chern-Simons theory) corresponds to the analytic/Ray-Singer torsion and not its inverse.

Comment: On reason this is confusing to me is that the regular $n=2$ Jones polynomial is related to the Alexander polynomial, not its inverse.